# Bringing up compensation question first when previous relationship exists

Tags: interviewing, salary, new-job, negotiation, compensation

I am interviewing at a large corporation (a famous cellphone/design company). I am at the point where they say they definitely want to move forward (and asking all kinds of paperwork related questions) and I said I'd like to move forward. However, the question about compensation did not come up (yet?).

There is a more complicated aspect to it: I have an existing relationship with that company: I worked there before (in a different group) and, more importantly, got already an offer half a year ago from the same group/recruiter. The offer (and position) was great but I ended up trying something else. I recently contacted them if there are other options. I mentioned to them that I am exploring other options but this is the only option where I am at this stage. Last time, the compensation discussion came at this point already (and that's usually the case). I would be happy to take the same offer they gave me half a year ago but I want to avoid that the offer ends up being worse. So I am unsure if I should bring up the question or not.

With this background:

- Is it likely they will just re-instantiate the offer from half a year ago?
- Shall I proactively ask about compensation or wait? (The usual recommendation is not bringing up this question first)
- In general, would my additional six months of "experience" be a ground for negotiating a better compensation than the one half a year ago? The last six months of experience are on a soft-skills level at best, but I am not sure if it is even reasonable to start negotiating.

Answer (score 2):

What you did or had in past is past. You went through a new round of interviews and proved your worth (again), so the salary negotiation should also happen afresh. It's entirely different thing that you'll be okay to accept the same amount of remuneration offer to you last time, but that is not a ground for not having a conversation / discussion at all.

Please ask them for a discussion on the remuneration part, just like you would in any other case.

That said, I'd advise to re-consider your worth according to the current market (and your experience and value-add that you bring to the organization) and negotiate accordingly, it's most likely to be upwards than the amount you were offered last time.

Comment: Good feedback! Would you bring it up proactively or wait until they bring it up (it will eventually happen but I am unsure if it will be to my disadvantage)

Comment: @divB What do you have to gain by waiting? Ask for it - it's not like you're asking for something undue - it's part of the negotiation process.

Comment: What they offered before is certainly something you can use in your negotiation. Though I would only bring it up if it was more than what you get offered this time around :)

Answer (score 2):

If it helps: translate this into something you might have more experience with.

> I was looking to buy a car six months ago.  The salesperson offered me
>   a price on a car, but I ended up deciding to use the bus.  Now I'm
>   back in the market for a car - should I tell the salesperson what the
>   prior offer was that I'm interested in taking?

Uh, no!  What on earth for?  As it is, there are three general possibilities:

- The salesperson was going to quote you an offer better than the one
  you had before... but as soon as you express interest in a worse
  offer, they're not going to do any better than that.
- The salesperson was going to quote you an offer worse than the one
  you had before, but would be willing to negotiate up to the better
  offer.
- The salesperson was going to quote you an offer worse than the one
  you had before, and isn't willing to match the prior offer.

There's zero benefit in coming right out and saying, "I would be happy with $X that was offered before" - because it sets an immediate ceiling in the bargain.  If they don't make an offer than good, then it's fine to bring it up as a negotiating point ("The salesperson last time offered $X")

Same thing with a job.  For all you know, the company has had terrible luck finding a qualified person for this position.  They may have gotten approval to add another 5k to the salary.  They might be willing to throw in additional vacation days.  But as soon as they hear "I'd be willing to accept it for $X which was offered before", you can bet that you're not going to get anything beyond that point.

Comment: That's a good perspective but I should add that I am not interviewing for the same position ... it's just the same group (also I get to choose between multiple positions in this group).

Comment: @divB - how is that relevant?  If "you're happy to take the same offer", and you tell the interviewer this, you're doing the same sort of immediate-ceiling cutoff.  Same way it doesn't matter if you say to the car salesperson "Oh, 6 months ago, someone offered to sell a *similar* car to me for $13k.  I'd be happy to take that offer."  Might not be the same car, but you did the same sort of "Well, not going to get it for any cheaper than $13k now" limitation.